# Storing user input as a string that allows for spaces and special characters?

Tags: bash

I have a script I'm trying to write which stores the users input as a string. These are the requirements: (that takes as input a string of characters, including special characters, white space, &c)

So far I'm using the following:

```
read -p 'input here' userinput
```

This is used to define the input as a stored variable. I was hinted that this needed regex to solve but I'm not sure where the regex comes in here because as far as I can tell read has no issue interpreting special characters.

The regex I did come up with in case this is needed is `[a-zA-Z0-9&*$#@!%\s]`.

I am just wondering where to use this regex to define the character class to the above regex.

Comment: `userinput` will contain anything the user types. What sort of verification of its value do you need to do next? Verify that it contains *only* the listed characters? Verify that it contains *all* the listed characters?

Comment: `IFS= read -p 'input here ' userinput` (no regex needed, you must suppress *word-splitting* by changing the *Internal Field Separator* to empty)

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to read an input line without messing with it is:

```
IFS= read -r -p 'input here' userinput
```

The `-r` ("raw") option tells read not to interpret backslash in the input as an escape (especially, at the end of the line it's not a continuation marker). The `IFS=` part is there because `read` will trim whitespace at the beginning and end of the input. "Whitespace" is defined by the `IFS` variable, so setting it to nothing means that nothing will be trimmed. Note that this assignment to `IFS` is a prefix to the `read` command, so it only affects that one command and doesn't have to be set back to normal afterward. Oh, and do *not* leave out the space between `IFS=` and `read`, or it'll mean something completely different.

BTW, that regex (characters allowed in input?) looks like it uses `\s` to represent space. That's a perlism, and many regex engines won't recognize it (or rather, will interpret it as two separate characters: a backslash and the letter "s"). Be sure to use the right regrex dialect for the tool you're using to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you need to disable word spitting and treat the backslash as a normal character using the `-r` option to `read`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS= read -rp 'input here ' userinput

echo "'$userinput'"
```

From man bash:

> `-r`   Backslash does not act as an escape character. The backslash is
>   considered to be  part of the line. In particular, a backslash-newline
>   pair may not be used as a line continuation.

Setting `IFS=` at the beginning of the command disables word-splitting allowing you to read leading and trailing whitespace.

**Example Use/Output**

With two leading and two trailing whitespace:

```
$ bash readall.sh
input here   two preceeding and two trailing
'  two preceeding and two trailing  '
```

With two leading and two trailing whitespace and your characters class with special characters:

```
$ bash readall.sh
input here   [a-zA-Z0-9&*$#@!%\s]
'  [a-zA-Z0-9&*$#@!%\s]  '
```

I see [@GordanDavisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) arrived at the same result. Great minds think alike.

Let me know if you have further questions.